# Xdebug .so file exists but still reported not found

Tags: php, xdebug

This is `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` content:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
```

and this is the error I get by running `php`:

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so (libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

However `/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so` exists and has read permission:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2078128 Jan 16 11:15 /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
```

Changing extension path to full path doesn't make a difference either.

What can be the reason?

Comment: 1) Have you tried without `.so` (`zend_extension=xdebug`)? 2) If you do the same for OPCache extension (that is loaded in the same way via zend_extension) -- does it work? (you can check `php -v` output to see if it's loaded). if one works and another does not... compare file permissions/ownership.

Comment: @LazyOne Thnak you. 1) tried, but almost the same error 2) `opcache.so` exists and is enabled and the ini file contains `zend_extension=opcache.so` 3) they both have same permissions, same ownership

Comment: You might need [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). Try `apt-get install musl-dev` (if it's Ubuntu) and then `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1` (or whatever is applicable for your OS).

Comment: @LazyOne That was the first thing I did before I ask the question but it didn't help. It just made `php` to get `segmentation fault`. I was guessing there should be something with module itself and I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/977257/unable-to-install-xdebug-undefined-symbol-zend-post-startup-cb) then renamed current `xdebug.so` and installed new one through `apt`: `apt-get install php-xdebug`and  that did it. Before that I was compiling source codes but the same error happened every time. (First corrupted version wasn't mine)

Comment: use the full path to your xdebug.so file like this zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so

Comment: I usually install `xdebug` through `pecl`. Is this an option for you instead of the `apt` version? Can you additionally add the result of `php -i | grep extension_dir` to you question?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so, kindly update your question or answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that shipped xdebug module was corrupted and installing it through `apt` solved the issue:

```
apt install php-xdebug
```

I also tried and compiled source code many times before installing it through `apt` but I got the same error every time I did. Yet the exact cause remains unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below link as I think it will solve your problem as it did for me
[Installing Xdebug](https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-high-sierra.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this content inside your `xdebug.ini` file

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1 <--- you can skip this
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using a mac, the C header files are no able to be reached via /usr/include. There  are a few ways to fix this, but compiling it yourself is probably the best way. I would recommend https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina if you don't want to turn SIP off.